# Search for Partial Fragments with deeply nested Tree

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

i am searching for a way to filter for documents using "filter path fragments" (for the lack of a better word). I have a deeply nested and recursive JSON structure and I dont want to write a monster query.

The query should look something like this

```
WHERE start_prop.next_prop.[here comes lots of different props which I want to "ignore"].next_inner_prop.[again stuff to ignore].final_prop = "Foo"
```

Maybe "ignore" is the wrong term here its more that the stuff in the `[]` should express: "yeah whatever is here"

or alternatively something like this

```
WHERE start_prop.next_prop.**.next_inner_prop.*.final_prop = "Foo"
```

I hope my question makes sense.

Thx

Comment: By definition I think you'd have to give up on any indexing coming into play, since indexes are built from the full path to the value, and it sounds like you don't have a known path to provide.  If so, there wouldn't be any efficiency gained in a Cosmos-side query vs grabbing the entire data set whole and filtering in client code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not supported. As Noah said, indexes are built from the full path to the value and you
don't have a known path. Also Cosmos query engine doesn't support `*` keyword. So this SQL can't work `WHERE start_prop.next_prop.**.next_inner_prop.*.final_prop = "Foo"`. You need to handle this on your client side.